# mySQL GROUP BY first letter and numbers 0-9

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a long list of universities and I want to group them by the first letter which is not a problem. But I have universities names that stats with numbers for example

```
14 Stars (London) Ltd t/a EUROPEAN COLLEGE FOR HIGHER EDUCATION (London)
3 D MORDEN COLLEGE
```

I want to put all names starting with numbers in one category "0-9"

Comment: can u show what have u tried ?

Comment: what is then your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this:

```
select
  case when name rlike '^[0-9]' then '0-9' else left(name,1) end as first_letter
  count(*)
from univ
group by first_letter
```

Answer (score 0):

you just use this to your query

```
   WHERE   title NOT RLIKE '^[A-Z]'       //this checks if first letter not from a-z
```

and you can also use `CASE` in your sql

```
  CASE  title NOT RLIKE '^[A-Z]'  then ........ END
  CASE  title  RLIKE '^[A-Z]'     then ........ END
```

Comment: since you didnt share what have you tried , so try to use this code in your query

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delays guys thanks a lot for your help. A friend of mine helped me yesterday and I sort out my problem here is the solution

`SELECT IF(substr(registered_name,1,1)REGEXP '^[0-9]','0-9',substr(registered_name,1,1)) Category,

  ...//rest of my query

  GROUP BY Category`